# JQuery Accordion Ajax Height issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, height, accordion

I'm having an issue implementing the JQuery Accordion.

Okay so basically what I need / am doing is the following:

Javascript:

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url:'MyServlet.jsp',
                type:"GET",
                async:true,
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(data)
                { 
                    $("#leaveRecordsTable").html(data);
                    $( "#leaveRecordsTable" ).accordion({
                          collapsible: true,
                          icons: null,
                          heightStyle: "content"
                        });
                }
            });
```

html:

```
<div id="leaveRecordsTable">
</div>
```

Okay so now what happens is that it gets the data correctly from my servlet, and it adds it perfectly to the DOM, but for some reason the height of each div inside the accordion is 0, which is a little space and I can't get that bigger.

I know it is caused by the ajax and dynamically adding the accordion because if I add my own headings and divs inside the "leaveRecordsTable" div, and not execute the ajax but execute the accordion method, it shows it perfectly with the correct heights.

Link to image to see what it looks like (Note: inside the accordion in each div there are textfields and data, so the height should be a lot bigger):

```
<a href='http://postimg.org/image/rp6eilhvh/' target='_blank'><img src='http://s22.postimg.org/rp6eilhvh/accordion.jpg' border='0' alt="accordion" /></a>
```

Data i'm sending from a servlet:

```
out.println("<h3>" + "Number: " + q + "</h3>");
out.println("<div style='height:0px;'>");
out.println("<table>");
out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td>From Date</td>");
out.println("<td><input type='text' id='from' name='from' readonly='readonly' style=' width:185px;'/></td>");
out.println("<td style='width:60px;'>To Date</td>");
out.println("<td><input type='text' id='to' name='to' readonly='readonly' style=' width:185px;'/></td>");
out.println("</tr>");
out.println("</table>");
out.println("</div>");
```

Basically this gets added to the "leaveRecordsTable" (a few of these headings & divs):

```
<h3>Number: 1</h3>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>From Date</td>
<td><input type='text' id='from' name='from' readonly='readonly' style=' width:185px;'/></td>
<td style='width:60px;'>To Date</td>
<td><input type='text' id='to' name='to' readonly='readonly' style=' width:185px;'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post the data you receive from the ajax request.

Comment: @PranayPrakash Please see my edits above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url:'MyServlet.jsp',
            type:"GET",
            async:true,
            dataType: "text",
            success:function(data)
            { 
                $("#leaveRecordsTable").html(data);
                $( "#leaveRecordsTable" ).accordion({
                      collapsible: true,
                      icons: null,
                      heightStyle: "content"
                    });
                $("#leaveRecordsTable").accordion("refresh");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still not working, but for testing purposes only i added an additional button with a method called when clicked, does this following:$("#leaveRecordsTable").accordion("destroy").accordion(); This works, but calling it after data is set, still not working?

Comment: Well I noticed one thing, you've got the same content for each div. So set height of the div using css, then change `heightStyle: "content"` to `heightStyle: "fill"` and remove the refresh line (i.e. `$("#leaveRecordsTable").accordion("refresh");`) Temme what happens

Comment: For testing purposes only which still shouldnt be a problem. For production each div will have same components but different data.

Comment: Oh... well hold on, I'm gonna replicate situation and find a solution :)

Comment: Sorry just noticed another problem. This accordion is within a Jquery tab (third tab). I remember reading something saying the accordion height is being set to 0 when it is not displayed? So in this case 3rd tab is not displayed so its set to 0 and when viewed it does not recalculate until i click the button to destroy and recreate the accordion. if i click the button while on another tab, and go back it breaks again i.e. height it is set to 0. I think that is the problem.

Comment: Okay so basically what i did was to add a listener on the 3rd tab and when clicked it should destroy and recreate the accordion. $("#leaveRecordsTable").accordion("destroy").accordion(); This fixed it unless anyone else got a better solution?

Comment: umm, `$("#leaveRecordsTable").accordion("destroy").accordion();` is nothing but `$("#leaveRecordsTable").accordion("refresh")` Just to make your code shorter

Comment: Oh and btw, I used my solution above. The one i posted in the answer. It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33485/discussion-between-pranay-prakash-and-foxticity)